# A variable of type Set<String> returns unreadable output format?

Tags: java, android

As shown in the code below, I want to list all the `keys` included in a `bundle` using the method `Set<String> set = compositeBundle.keySet();` and I try to display the contents of the variable `set` using `set.toString()` but it return something like this `xxxxx@xxxx`

How to display the contents of the variable `Set <String> set`?

Code:

```
Bundle compositeBundle = getMeetingPointFixDataInBundle(getNewMeetingPointFixBundle(), locLatEt, locLngEt, 
                    almanec.getTime(), almanec.getDate());

            //separateBundleData(compositeBundle);
            Set<String> set = compositeBundle.keySet();

            Log.d(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "Lsit of the KEYS contained in the Bundle is, "+set.toString());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the set in order to get its value.

```
 Set<String> set ;
         Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
         while(it.hasNext()){
             String key = it.next();
         }
```

Currently, you are printing the String returned from the `Set implementation` of `set` variable.

Comment: @DownVoter: Bother to mention the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 1):

using a combination of

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

and

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29)

you could do

```
Arrays.toString (set.toArray ());
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats the hash code of the object, toString() method of this object doensn't return string of all object's values. Sets may contain different types inside.

use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));`

working example :

```
  Set<String> set = new HashSet();
  set.add("first string");
  set.add("second string");

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
```